# Why is my Elastic Load Balancer receiving GET and POST requests for domains not linked to my account and is responding with 200 codes?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I have an ELB set up onto my two EC2 servers.

I have ELB access logging sending the requests it receives to S3.

At the moment I am just doing development and testing, yet I'm noticing my ELB getting hits like:

```
"POST http://us.ubsmsp.com:80/Gateway.aspx?method=UserBehaviourService.AMFMobileEvent.SendEvent HTTP/1.1"

"GET http://fundbox.com:80/ HTTP/1.1"
```

Both of these apparently received 200 response codes both from the ELB and my back end EC2 servers? I don't understand how this is possible.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Simple, really... yet, complex.

From the back-end: your application isn't checking the incoming `Host:` header, or if it is, it's got a default rule that still allows it to return some kind of response that's accompanied by a `200 OK`, or (unlikely but pretty bad) your web server or application is behaving as an open proxy and forwarding those requests on to the specified destination.

Punch the hostname of the ELB itself into your browser.  Your web server will probably return your site's main page, and that'a probably not what you want. (Search engines can then index your content under the ELB domain, which is almost certainly not desirable).  Modify your web server configuration so that this hostname, and any other unexpected hostname, returns an error, such as `502 Bad Gateway` or `400 Bad Request`.

Note one important exception to the above: if the `Host:` header of an incoming request contains one of the instance's IP addresses, and the `User-Agent:` header contains a value like `ELB-HealthChecker/1.0`, and the path matches you've specified in your ELB [HTTP health check](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/ElasticLoadBalancing/latest/APIReference/API_HealthCheck.html) configuration, you still need to return `200 OK` to avoid ELB declaring your instance unhealthy.  Be certain you account for that exception.

After this, these spurious requests should be met with an appropriate error, and the new error code should be logged.

Next, why would ELB forward these requests?  Because ELB doesn't screen requests by `Host:` header.  Any number of your domains can be hosted behind a single ELB.  ELB is not designed to screen them.

Finally: how did they arrive in the first place?  Several possibilities, virtually all of which are outside your control.

Perhaps the most likely is DNS caching.  The IP addresses assigned to ELB are dynamic and subject to change at any time.  If a user agent (browser, spider, etc.) or DNS server or CDN edge or any number of other entities has cached the other site's former IP address, which is now your ELB IP address, then requests will incorrectly be sent to your site.

This could also be attributable to an internal error by ELB's interface to the global DNS, which could have incorrectly responded to a query for an unrelated site... with an IP address associated to to your ELB.  (I'm not saying this happens routinely, only that it's a possibility).  Imagine my surprise one day when surfing to one of my sites, hosted on ELB, I got a message that was very obviously from a dropbox.com web server, reporting an "unexpected error."  My sites have *zero* interaction with dropbox, and although I duplicated the error several times in short succession, it cleared up before I finished investigating.  I assume if dropbox had looked at their logs that day, they might have asked, "Why are we getting requests for one of @Michael-Sqlbot's sites in our ELB logs?"  (Perhaps not their exact words.)

It's also possible that a malicious user is scanning ELBs to see if the applications behind them are behaving in an unusual way that might expose a security vulnerability.

Back to the top, now... Configure your back-end web server or application to throw an error on requests for unexpected `Host:` header values on incoming requests... and, after that, these requests in your logs can be largely disregarded unless they become significant in number.

Comment: Michael your answer is outstanding, thank you for the detailed and easy-to-understand explanation.

Comment: @Hardworker, thank you.  Note I've added one caveat to the answer: be careful that you don't break your ELB health checks as you tighten down the screws on your configuration.  The `Host:` header will be an IP address, and the `User-Agent:` and path will be as described above.